# What are the official draw rules in American Pool Checkers?

Tags: checkers

In the official rules of [American Pool Checkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pool_Checkers), what are the conditions for a draw to be declared?

Answer (score 2):

The American Pool Checkers website "americanpoolcheckers.us" is essentially dead (deliberately not linked because of a bad HTTPS certificate), but was fortunately archived by the Wayback Machine, so we can get [the rules from 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20210614152121/http://americanpoolcheckers.us/index.php/history/apca-tournament-rules-of-play). These include:

> 26. In certain end-game positions, when one of the sides appears stronger than the other, the stronger side is required to complete a win within thirty moves. If after thirty moves the pieces of both sides remain unchanged the game is declared a draw. [ ... ]
> 27. “13” COUNT RULE: The lone king must be caught before the player with the lone king counts thirteen, or the game is declared a draw.
> 28. If the lone king has the long line (4-29) and the stronger side refuses to accept the draw then the stronger side has to catch the lone king within five moves

Comment: Cool, thanks. Weird that it just says "certain end-game positions" without specifying what those positions are!

Comment: @TomekCzajka, I am guessing they call it "certain end-game positions" since the list of those position is not final yet and from time to time another position is being added.